# Incorrect Resizing image?

Tags: swift, uiimage, image-resizing, uigraphicscontext

I need explications about this code

```
 // Resizing Image
 let size = CGSizeMake(rect.size.width, rect.size.height)
 print (size)
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 1)
 _image.drawInRect(rect)
 let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
 print(resizedImage.size)
```

This my console :

```
(18.5, 18.5)
(19.0, 19.0)
```

Can you explain why my resizing does not work correctly. Why my resizedImage is not 18.5 x 18.5 ?

Answer (score 4):

You cannot create an image that has a size of 18.5 pixels. There is no meaning for half a pixel. So the system rounds up your values.